# Apache-Ubuntu: can not access my site using IP address

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, apache2

I have a web site running on **ubuntu 16.04** vps with Apache.
recently i can not access main web page using its IP‌ address.
please help me debug my server configuration.

main-site.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin M.Mahmoodi@avanikan.com
    ServerName X.X.X.X
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**apache2.conf** contains:

```
...

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all

</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
</Directory>

 <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
...
```

and **/etc/hosts** :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   guest-desktop
185.211.88.62   student.aut.ac.ir       student



# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Seems like the php module is not loaded.

Comment: how to solve this?

Comment: Why are referring to be an Apache settings issue ?. Have you tried to create "index.html" page under your website folder "i assume its /var/www/html" and test this page. It might be your website settings not Apache dear

Comment: I have some index.html by now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress does not execute PHP file](https://serverfault.com/questions/883169/wordpress-does-not-execute-php-file)